# How to prevent user to upload a big file with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin). In one of the views the user can upload a picture, but I want to show an error if he is trying to upload a file bigger than x size. How can I do that? This is my code so far:

```
form(html: { multipart: true }) do |f|
 f.inputs "Bs" do
   f.input :latitude, as: :hidden
   f.input :longitude, as: :hidden
   f.input :name
   f.input :picture, as: :file
 end
   f.actions
end
```

Comment: Size as in file size or resolution?

Comment: Should the error occur before or after the upload?

Comment: @Joel Calado : It would be size in file size, but it can also be size in resolution.

Comment: @Robin : It would be before.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to write a custom validation in your model, especially if you are using paperclip as it doesn't allow to pass function that limits size.

the validation would look something like this

```
validate :validate_image_size

def validate_image_size
  if document.file? && document.size > get_current_file_size_limit
    errors.add_to_base(" ... Your error message")
  end
end

  private

def get_current_file_size_limit
  10.megabytes # This will dynamically change
end
```

Comment: I thought doing a before_action, the problem is that I don't know how to access the file before the saving and how to prevent the saving if the image is bigger. 

I suppose that the file would be stored in :picture, but what can I do in the validation to prevent ActiveAdmin to continue with the saving process?

Comment: The custom validation is a before_action. Have you tried implementing.  should do exactly what you want it to do